# android how to pass an object to a new class

Tags: android, oop

I have the following Activity

```
public class BmiHistory extends Activity {


public Cursor cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.bmihistory);
    final DatabaseHandler databaseOpen = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    final SQLiteDatabase db = databaseOpen.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from bmi", null);
    startManagingCursor(c1);
    c1.moveToFirst();
    this.cursor = c1; 
    while(!c1.isAfterLast()) {
        System.out.println(c1.getString(2));
        c1.moveToNext();
    }
    c1.close();


    BmiGraph drawView = new BmiGraph(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);

}


}
```

I have the following class called from this activity

```
public class BmiGraph extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();


public BmiGraph(BmiHistory context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    System.out.println(context.toString());
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    ...
}


}
```

My question is how can I make the data from the cursor in the Activity available to the second class in order to plot a graph?

Many thanks

Comment: Add a setter method in `BmiGraph` and call it from `BmiHistory`

Comment: Thanks K-ballo, I attempted that - but I dont know the semantics very well

Comment: Its mostly just syntactic, not semantics.. You will have to learn _Java_ if you want to write _Android_ applications.

Comment: Im trying - can you give me an example?

Comment: No, sorry, I cannot synthesize in an example how to program in _Java_. Pick up a tutorial, I'm sure there are lots of good ones!

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the constructor of the BmiGraph class to accept your cursor as an input (see below).  Then you will have access to your cursor from within the BmiGraph class.

```
public class BmiGraph extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();

Cursor _someCursor;    

public BmiGraph(BmiHistory context, Cursor someCursor) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    System.out.println(context.toString());

    _someCursor = someCursor
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    ...
}


}
```